# How is the variable step in "Colliding Mice" in QT changed?

Tags: c++, qt

I am reading through [this example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-graphicsview-collidingmice-example.html) of a QT-project based on C++. A class called **Mouse** is defined (in a file mouse.h) inheriting from **QGraphicsItem**, and this class has a method which is declared as follows:

```
protected:
    void advance(int step) Q_DECL_OVERRIDE;
```

the method **advance** is (re)implemented in a file mouse.cpp and starts as follows:

```
void Mouse::advance(int step)
{
    if (!step)
        return;
... and some more code ...
```

---

These are the only three places the variable **step** is ever mentioned in the entire program (I carried out a search in each of the source files). The method **advance** is called from a **QTimer**-instance in the main.cpp file, but (strangely?) with no parameters. However, debugging with a breakpoint right at the start of the **advance** method, shows that **step** cycles between values 0 and 1.

Does anyone know why that is? The tutorial in the link just states that it does so, but gives no explanation of how its value is set or changed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read the documentation more carefully. The `advance()` method called by the `QTimer` is a member of `QGraphicsScene`.  `QGraphicsScene::advance()` calls all the `QGraphicsItem`'s `advance( int phase )` in the [scene in two phases](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsscene.html#advance), the first phase notifies the items are about to change (when argument is 0), and the second is for the actual change (the argument is 1).

Comment: Fantastic! That makes perfect sense now.

Answer (score 2):

In main, `advance()` is not called. In the call to connect here :

```
 QObject::connect(&timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), &scene, SLOT(advance()));
```

The signal emited by the timer is connected to the `advance()` slot of the [`QGraphicsScene`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsscene.html#advance), not to the `advance(int)` of the `Mouse` class (which is not a slot).

The `advance()` slot of the `scene` then calls [`QGraphicsItem::avance(int)`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsitem.html#advance) for all items, when the timer emits `timeout()`.

Comment: Thank you for your contribution, which also helped clarifying what was at play here!